# Is there a word for phrases that have an adverb and an adjective starting with same letter in it?

Tags: adjectives, phrases

Is there a word for phrases that have an adverb and an adjective starting with same letter in it?

Example:

- Moderately mindful
- Brilliantly bold
- Cunningly clever etc.

Comment: Note this pattern is adverb and adjective, not two adjectives. (Remember most English adverbs are formed by adding "-ly" to an adjective.)

Comment: Thank you @aschepler! I'll update the question.

Comment: From the full OED: [**alliteration**, noun](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5324): *The commencement of adjacent or closely connected words with the same sound or letter; **an instance of this***. But personally I'd be perfectly happy to see ***an alliterative*** used as a noun, reserving the explicitly nouny form ***alliteration*** for the *process / writing style* sense.

Answer (score 4):

Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers, where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?

The term is *alliteration*, but it's not restricted to only two words, or even two adjectives.

Per Merriam & Webster:

> *[alliteration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alliteration)* - the repetition of usually initial consonant sounds in two or more neighboring words or syllables (such as wild and woolly, threatening throngs)